# Cannot Load OpenSSL in IIS

Tags: openssl, isapi, xmlsec, isapi-extension

I am using xmlsec to sign XML documents. This works fine on my development machine when I'm running a local executable. However when I compile this to run as an ISAPI dll (under a local instance of IIS 7 on Windows 10) I get an error when making the call to

```
xmlSecCryptoDLLoadLibrary('openssl')
```

I have checked the permissions on the xmlsec and openssl binaries and made sure the IIS_IUSRS (the application pool virtual user) has execute rights.

What else should I be checking to get this working (NB: it has to be deployed via IIS)

Comment: I've just copied the xmlsec binaries into the directory that the w3wp.exe process executes from and this alleviates the problem. Obviously I don't want this in a prod environment, so I'm guessing xmlsec will have a config setting somewhere ...